# Get table data from dynamically selected table in LINQ C#

Tags: c#

I obtain a table reference as such:

```
 public static void MyDataGrabbingClass<T>(MyModelCls Model) where T : class
        {
            DataContext dc = new DataContext(Config.ConnectionString);
            //var ITable = (Devart.Data.Linq.ITable)dc.GetType().GetProperty(tableName).GetValue(dc, null);
            //var table = dc.GetTable(ITable.GetType());
            //var dataModel = dc.Mapping;
            //Type tableType = ITable.GetType();
            //var t = dc.Mapping.MappingSource.GetModel(typeof(DataContext)).GetMetaType(tableType);
            var table = dc.GetTable<T>();
        }
```

I want to then select the specific columns of data using:

```
var Query = from c in table where Model.DateToColName  < Model.DateTo select (Model.ColSelections);
```

obviously I need to somehow map the table column, and not use Model.DateToColName in the where clause, how do I do this?

In other words, with my dynamically chosen table, how do i get the column data from a string column name

Comment: I did something very similar to this a few years ago (well, quite a few years ago now....). It did not involve Generics. It involved using an Interface implemented by all classes/tables that I wanted to query dynamically. Sorry I can't be more specific - it was in a previous job and I don't have access to the source now. I will also say that in the end I did it just to show it could be done; there were better ways of implementing the functionality required.

Comment: I have so many tables and columns that it would take a long time to do this I think

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think you'll be able to construct a dynamic query in LINQ (at least not easily).  Take a look at [Dapper.NET](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) - it's a "simple object mapper for .NET" that might work for you, created by the makers of StackOverflow.  For example, using Dapper.NET, your method might look like:

```
public static void MyDataGrabbingClass<T>(MyModelCls Model) where T : class
{
   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnecrion(Config.ConnectionString)
   {
       conn.Open();

       string tableName = ...;
       string dateToColumnName = ...;

       // depending on how dateToColumnName is constructed, ensure it is not a SQL-injection risk
       if (tableName.Any(c => !char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
           throw new ArgumentException("Invalid table name.");
       if (dateToColumnName.Any(c => !char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
           throw new ArgumentException("Invalid column name.");

       // Query is a
       var results = conn.Query<T>("SELECT * FROM [" + tableName + "] WHERE [" + dateToColumnName + "] < @DateTo", new { DateTo = someDate });

       ...

   }
}
```

**Security concern:** Dynamic SQL can be susceptible to SQL injection - so be sure that the dateToColumnName variable is not from user-input, or is sanitized or validated appropriately.